# How to use std::function in JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, lambda, java-native-interface

I have a C++ class that has a class member like following:

```cpp
class FilterPipeline{
    std::vector<std::function<bool(Object&, Object&)> > filters;

public:

    void addFilter(std::function<bool(Object&, Object&)> filter){    
        this->filters.push_back(filter);
    }

    bool eval(Object &o){
        bool state = true;

        for(int i=0; i<this->filters.size(); i++)
        {
            if(!this->filters[i]((*this), o))
            {
                state = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return state;
    }
}
```

In Java, I want to be able to pass in an lambda expression into `addFilter` method and call eval method in the end to do evaluation.

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Filter{
    public boolean test(Object o1, Object o2);
} 

FilterPipeline p = new FilterPipline();
p.addFilter((o1, o2) -> {
     boolean result;
     // do something here
     return result;
});

if(p.eval(new Object()){
    // do something
}
```

How should I implement this in using JNI? I was thinking about using functional interface, but I'm really new to the JNI development, so I'm not really sure what should I do here.

Comment: You need to provide more details. How do you intend to use this class from your Java code?

Comment: @Michael Just updated the question.

Comment: Q: Wny don't you just use a nice, simple, C-style callback function???

Comment: @paulsm4 because I want to be able to use lambda expression

Comment: That's still not enough information. What does your Java `FilterPipeline` class look like? How does it interact with the native code?

Answer (score -2):

Have u

1) linkded header files (c++ standard library)

2) #include

3) using namespace std;

etc ?

If your new to JNI read some tutorial first...

Comment: This should be a comment as this does not answer the question.